# iOS source build setting 'search path'

Tags: ios, xcode, build, build-settings, search-path

I am trying to use [this project](https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C) in my iOS app. In the instructions, it says:

- Switch to the Build Settings page, go down to the Search Paths section. (if you have trouble finding it, type "header search" in the search field)
  Add the absolute path to the source code directory to the path list.

How does that mean. What value should I add in the search path section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will download the source code of this library and saved it somewhere on your machine. Then you have to add the path to this source files in the header search path (there xcode will search for the header files you will try to use in your app). It can be something like:

> "/Users/yourUser/yourProject/yourLibrarySource"